# OpenLiberty support SprintBoot 3.0 or not?

Tags: spring-boot-maven-plugin, open-liberty

With the latest open liberty version, Anyone knows if it supports the sprintBoot-3.0 feature ?   Thanks
springBoot-3.0

Is there anyone share your server.xml with sprintboot 3.0 for open liberty ?

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0 requires Jakarta EE 10 which isn't yet available on Liberty. I have got it working on the beta using a spring boot war and Jakarta EE 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Open Liberty does not officially support Spring Boot 3.0. However, there is ongoing work regarding this feature.

I found an open pull request on the Open Liberty GitHub repository which seems to be in progress of adding support for Spring Boot 3.0. Here is the link for your reference: [Open Liberty Issue #19982](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/19982)

Please note that since this feature is still in development, it might not be fully stable or may not support all functionalities of Spring Boot 3.0 yet. It is recommended to keep an eye on the official Open Liberty documentation and GitHub page for the latest updates on this feature.

As for the server.xml configuration with Spring Boot 3.0, it would not be possible to provide one until the support is officially released and stable.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 3.0 capability is now available in the [23.0.0.8-beta](https://openliberty.io/blog/2023/08/03/23.0.0.8-beta.html#sp3) release of Open Liberty.